# Why does textmode=password causes issue in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, textbox, passwords

I am facing a very peculiar issue.

I have set textmode of an asp.net textbox to Password but it causes a problem i.e. it picks other passwords from cookies even it has nothing to do with my page.

And setting it to password also affects my another textbox with is set to SingleLine mode but when I remove Password textmode then it works correctly.

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword1" TextMode="Password" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>

 <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserLogin1" TextMode="SingleLine" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: Try to add `autocomplete="off"` to your `asp:TextBox`

Comment: i tried, no effect

Comment: I think earlier you had the textmode=singleline which might have got some auto complete sugesstion, after you change it to password it still shows the same. Try to delete those sugesstion and type another password and see if that gets shown in auto complete

Comment: This is default browser behavior, not a website issue.

Comment: @VDWWD and there must be a solution ?

Comment: @Krishna: I did but no luck :(

Comment: can you try another browser and see if you see the same passwords ?

Comment: @Krishna same issue

Comment: @Covert add a password textbox and hide it with css. test if you need it above or below the current one. That will trick the browser into filling the hidden one.

Comment: I am facing the same issue on Chrome browser and others it is working fine

Answer (score 0):

Regarding this

> it picks other passwords from cookies even it has nothing to do with my page.

I think it a browser functionality which automatically populates saved password for you. So when you have type as "password", it shows you some password. Try to clear saved password and then you will see blank textbox.

I am not sure about the second issue.

Comment: Thank You Pang For Edit.

Answer (score 0):

I added dummy text box

```
<asp:TextBox ID="dummy" runat="server" style="display:none"></asp:TextBox>
```

under the textbox which was showing prefilled data from cache. It solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use type="Password" instead of TextMode="Password"